# Path-connected is connected (proof verification)

Tags: general-topology

Assume that $A$ is path-connected, and $U\subseteq A$ which is clopen in respect of $A$. Assume that $U\neq\emptyset \land U\neq A$/ then there are $x\in U \;\; y\in A-U$. From path connected there is $\gamma:[0,1]\to A$ which is continous. and as $[0,1] = \gamma^{-1}(A)=\gamma^{-1}(U)\uplus \gamma^{-1}(A-U)$ , and U,A-U are open

- (A-U is open because U is also closed.)

then we have the connected interval $[0,1]$ written as a disjoint union of open sets which is contradictory to the connectives of the interval $[0,1]$.

Does this make sense?
I also want to prove that the interval is connected, but I couldn't do it: Tried to state that if it wasn't connected then by taking $x$ in one of the sets and $y$ in the second set then the interval $(x,y)$ satisfies that for every $z$ in the interval: $z$ belongs to just one of the sets, and also that there is a ball around $z$ that is contained in that subspace. Hence, if the two sets are not empty then at least one of them must have a *boundary point* that is contained in the set and that leads to a contradictory because we wrote the interval as a union of the open sets without the boundary.

but I wasn't able to formalise that.. (maybe there is a need to build a sequence of points that leads to a contradictory?)

Thanks.

Comment: You're thinking too hard.  Suppose your space is disconnected, so you have $X=A \cup B$ (both non empty, disjoint). What can you say about a path from $a \in A$ and $b \in B$?

Answer (score 1):

I can't decipher the symbols you're using, so I can't really say if you're correct tor not. Here is the standard answer;

If $X=A \cup B$  with $A,B$ disjoint and nonempty and open in $X$. then pick $a \in A$ and $b \in B$. There is a cts map, $f:[0,1] \rightarrow X$ with $f(0)=a,f(1)=b$. Then:
$$f^{-1}(X)=f^{-1}(A \cup B)=f^{-1}(A)\cup f^{-1}(B)=[0,1]$$

This implies $[0,1]$ is disconnected (why?), a contradiction.

Comment: This is really what I tried to say :p, but also tried to understand the connectivity of [0,1].

Comment: Do you know $mathbb{R}$ is connected?  To approach [0,1]; suppose not; then $[0,1]=A \cup B$ such that blah blah...WLOG assume $1 \in B$ then look at sup(A), contradict completeness of $R$.

Comment: then, if sup(A)=1, B cant be open, because every neighborhood of 1 is not disjoint to A. 
But if sup(A)<1, what happens then? Does the following holds?
lets say sup(A)<1 then: if inf(B)>sup(A) we lack part of the interval. and also if inf(B)=sup(A) we still lack that one point (right?!). at last we must get inf(B)<sup(A) and because sets are open we get contradiction again

Comment: is that right? is there more elegance way to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

It’s much easier. Suppose $X$ were disconnected and $\{A,B\}$ a disconnection by open sets.

As both sets are non-empty pick $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. Let $f: I \to X$ be a continuous path from $a$ to $b$ ( so $I = [0,1]$ in the usual topology which makes it a connected space).

Then $f[I]$ is connected by continuity of $f$ but $\{A,B\}$ disconnects it, contradiction.